# Indentation of source block result

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

How should one indent text in `org-mode` with `org-indent-mode` disabled?
I expect something like this:

```
* A
  Some text.
  - item 1
  - item 2

** B
   More text.
```

*EDIT:* This seems to depend on the variable `org-adapt-indentation`. I have it set to `t`.

### Incorrect indentation of babel output

But then this output of the evaluation below (using org-babel) is incorrectly indented:

```
* Headline showing result indentation

  Some text aligned with the headline.
  Evaluate lisp expression ~(require 'ob-python)~ and then run the code
  block below.

  #+BEGIN_SRC python :results output
    for i in range(10):
        print(str(i))
  #+END_SRC

  #+RESULTS:
  #+begin_example
  0
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  6
  7
  8
  9
#+end_example

  After running the output on the previous line is incorrectly indented.
```

How do can I use org-mode in such a way that evaluated output (more than 10 lines long) is correctly indented?
I suspect there is an option to fix this or, if not, this may be a bug but my experience with emacs and `org-mode` is limited.
I used emacs 24.5.1 with the -q option and an empty home directory just to make sure it is not a misconfiguration.

Comment: My understanding is that you should not manually indent (add physical spaces) blocks/sections in org-mode. `org-indent-mode` is to make this default non-indented format more visually pleasing.

Comment: I considered that possibility, but came to the conclusion that not indenting the text is not the default behaviour.
When using `M-right` and `M-left` the indentation is added automatically (at least in org 8.3 by default) when _not_ in `org-indent-mode`. Also deadline and notes are indented by default to match the headline level.